# web scraping with beautiful soup in - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the data in the section called "Stock Spotlight" in the table labeled "Most Active".  From:
https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/overview/overview.asp

## And print something like this:

```
[('General Electric Co', '6.52'),
 ('Tonix Pharmaceuticals Holding Corp', '1.06'),
 ('Carnival Corp', '12.00'),
 ('Uber Technologies Inc', '21.33'),
 ('American Airlines Group Inc', '10.33'),
 ('MGM Resorts International', '9.11'),
 ('Snap Inc', '10.09'),
 ('Halliburton Co', '5.05')]
```

## My code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/overview/overview.asp'

def pull_active(url):

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    response     = requests.get(url)
    results_page = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')
    data         = results_page.find_all('table', class_='stock-spotlight-table') # ???  
    table        = data.append(tbody.get_text()) # ??? the html element that contains multiple <tr> elements 

    table_rows   = []
    for i in table:
        label    = i.find('td', class_='truncateMeTo1').text # ?
        val      = i.find('td', class_='colPrimary'   ).text # ?
        table_rows.append((Stocks, Latest))             # ??? add the labels and values to the empty list as tuples 
    return table_rows

pull_active(url)
```

Nothing is happening when I run the above code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. basically read_html reads all the tables on the page and you can get the desired ones.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://markets.on.nytimes.com/research/markets/overview/overview.asp'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[0]
print(df)
```